# define book class with member function and store value

Tags: c++, function, class, member

Can someone please help me with the below requirement

Class book that  that contains attributes BookId, BookName, and Price. It also contain member function to input and show its attributes.

Write another class Writer that contains that contains the attributes of WriterName, Address and NumberofBooks written by him. It contains array of book objects as iys member. The length of array should be 5 to store the data of five books.
It should also contain a member function to input and display its attributes.

[I found a solution on google with below code](http://www.cppforschool.com/assignment/class-object-sol/class-book.html) but it appears it is useful for my half requirement.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
class BOOK
{
    int BOOKNO;
    char BOOKTITLE[20];
    float PRICE;
    void TOTAL_COST(int N)
    {
        float tcost;
        tcost=PRICE*N;
        cout<<tcost;
    }
public:
    void INPUT()
    {
        cout<<"Enter Book Number ";
        cin>>BOOKNO;
        cout<<"Enter Book Title ";
        gets(BOOKTITLE);
        cout<<"Enter price per copy ";
        cin>>PRICE;
    }

    void PURCHASE()
    {
        int n;
        cout<<"Enter number of copies to purchase ";
        cin>>n;
        cout<<"Total cost is ";
        TOTAL_COST(n);
    }
};

void main()
{
    BOOK obj;
        obj.INPUT();
        obj.PURCHASE();
        getch();
    }
```

Comment: Hello.  What is the question you're asking?

Comment: I would replace `char BOOKTITLE[20];` with a std::string.

Comment: BTW, common coding convention is to use ALL CAPS for constants, such a `MAX_BOOK_TITLE_LENGTH`.

Comment: Dear Thomas,

I am asking how I should mend this code to incorporate following requirement

Write another class Writer that contains that contains the attributes of WriterName, Address and NumberofBooks written by him. It contains array of book objects as iys member. The length of array should be 5 to store the data of five books. It should also contain a member function to input and display its attributes.

Comment: What is an `iys` member?  Haven't come across the term `iys`.

Comment: You have been asked to write some code that models a book -> author relationship. An author has a name, an address and collection of books they have published. A book has an id, a name and a price. 

An author therefore has a 1 to many relationship with a book. in other words, one author can have written many books. 

Before you search for code to solve your problem, you need to understand how to model the problem. Once you know how to model the problem, you won't need to copy/pase code, it's simply transcribing the mental model to words.

Comment: You may want to change `BOOKTITLE` to use `std::string`.  Character arrays can overflow.  Also with character arrays, you should be using the `str*()` family of functions, such as `strcmp` and `strlen`.

Comment: Lastly, the `main` function has a return type of `int`, so it can return a status to the Operating System.  Search the internet for "C++ EXIT_SUCCESS" or "C++ EXIT_FAILURE".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *contain* an instance of an object you declare a member of that type in your class:

```
class Writer
{
  const size_t MAX_BOOKS_WRITTEN = 5U;
  Book         books_written[MAX_BOOKS_WRITTEN];
};
```

In the above class, "that contains that contains" an array of books written.

Comment: you mean I just incorporate the above code shared by you in the end of my code?

Comment: You can use it however you want.  You could place the `Writer` class into a separate header file and method implementations into a separate source file.  You could also place everything into one `main` file.  There are many possibilities.

Comment: @user3340643 - I implore you not to simply copy and paste code, you will not learn anywhere near as efficiently that way and may even completely stunt your growth as a programmer. This is a fairly trivial problem that you should be able to solve by breaking the problem down into chunks, doing some rudimentary research/learning and then coding a solution - this will give you a jump pad to the rest of OOP and generally thinking like a programmer. Just my 2 cents though